# Law of Iterated Expectation for RVs with Stieltjes Integral.

Tags: probability, measure-theory, expected-value, conditional-expectation, stieltjes-integral

I want to show that the law of iterated expectations $E[E[X|Y]] = E[X]$ holds for RVs that are not discretely or continuously distributed.

In specific in our class we have defined the expectation of X in terms of the Riemann-Stieltjes integral:

$E[X] =  \int_{\mathbb{R}} x d F_X$

What I got so far:

E[E[X|Y]] = $\int_{\mathbb{R}} \int_{\mathbb{R}} x dF_{X|Y} dF_Y$

In the discrete and continuous case we use the definition of the conditional expectation $P(X|Y) P(Y) = P(X\cap Y)$.

My idea was to use the above definition to to define a product measure  $F_{X|Y} F_Y = F_{X,Y} = F_{Y|X} F_X$ and apply Fubini's Theorem twice.

\begin{align}
\int_{\mathbb{R}} \int_{\mathbb{R}} x dF_{X|Y} dF_Y &= \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} x dF_{X,Y} = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \int_{\mathbb{R}} x dF_{Y|X} dF_X\\
 &= \int_{\mathbb{R}} x  dF_X \int_{\mathbb{R}} 1 dF_{Y|X} = \int_{\mathbb{R}} x  dF_X = E[X]
\end{align}

Using the fact that any probability measure integrates to one. Is this a valid application of Fubini's Theorem?

I know that we use the Riemann-Stieltjes Integral to integrate over function with non-continuous CDFs. Can I generally think about the measure $dF(t)$ being equivalent to $dP(X\leq t)$?

Any help or suggestions for introductory readings is appreciated.